# Sorting with Multivalued Field in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, solrnet

I Have a Solr index that stores Price in a multivalued field for each Product.

I need to sort the result set by Price where the Price is Low to high and High to Low.

I try to use sorting on Price it's showing Error You can't sort on multivalued=True fields.

below is my solr XML

```
<arr name="sellprice">
<float>195.0</float>
<float>136.5</float>
<float>10.0</float>
</arr>
```

in schema.xml

```
 <field name="sellprice" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

In C# Code

```
ISolrQueryResults<ProductTest2> powerArticles = solr.Query(new
SolrQuery("WebCategory_Id:10") && new SolrQueryInList("FilterID",
    146), new QueryOptions { FilterQueries = new[] { new
SolrQueryByRange<decimal>("sellprice", 10, 40) }, OrderBy = new[] {
    new SolrNet.SortOrder(sellprice, desc) } });
```

Can somebody explain with some good example?

Answer (score 14):

Sorting on multivalued fields does not work fine with Solr.

Documentation

> Sorting can be done on the "score" of the document, or on any multiValued="false" indexed="true" field provided that field is either
>   non-tokenized (ie: has no Analyzer) or uses an Analyzer that only
>   produces a single Term (ie: uses the KeywordTokenizer)

When you want to sort the products from low to high or high to low, what price will Solr pick ? As from the example you have a Sell price of 0 as well as 195 ?

[The function queries also do not allow to use max or min on the multivalued fields.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2522)

The option you have to save the highest and lowest sell price as single valued fields, and use those fields for sorting.

```
highest_sell_price=195
lowest_sell_price=0
```

and use these fields for sorting.

Comment: if i pick low to high then min price and high to low then Max price.

Comment: Updated the answer, there seems to be no direct way for doing this.

Comment: Thanks for your Quick response. I have also posted a new Question please suggest me with an example.                     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846018/data-import-in-solr-from-multiple-entity

Comment: If it answers your question, might help to accept the answer.